# In what order does maven run the phases given by composite command?

Tags: java, maven

If I run `mvn validate clean package` or `mvn clean package`, I don't see `validate` or `clean` phase running.

Instead I see directly package phase running.

Aren't composite commands valid for maven command line?

Comment: How do you see only package running? Post your pom, and post the output of your command.

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not print the lifecycles or phases, but it does print each *plugin goal* run by the build. When running `mvn clean compile` with maven 3.5.3, I see the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/myuser/myproject/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
...
```

I don't know why maven is not more verbose about printing lifecycles and phases. Maybe someone with deeper understanding or inside perspective can contribute. Please also see [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in the Maven doc.